# Running a Tkinter window and a Matplotlib plot simultaneously

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am writing a Python script that visualizes data from a pressure sensor, and performs timed tests. I am plotting the data on a live Matplotlib graph, and I also have a Tkinter window to display a timer, as well as the instantaneous sensor reading. Here is the sequence of what I'm thinking so far:

1. Ask user to enter the amount of time for the test in a Tkinter window. Dispose of this window after user enters time
2. Create live plot and start reading data
3. open Tkinter window to display timer and instantaneous data
4. When test is done, dispose of Tkinter window and graph. Prompt user to enter the amount of time for the next test. Repeat steps 2-4

Here is the code I have so far. I have left out some unimportant things in the interest of saving space:

```
#imports
#left out imports to save space

#ADS code
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115(address=0x48, busnum=1)
GAIN = 1

global t
#ask user for input time
def gettime():
  global t
    def gettext(self):
        global e
        global t
        string = e.get()
        t = int(string)
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
root.title('Enter the time')
root.bind('<KP_Enter>', gettext)

labelfont = ('times', 70, 'bold')

label = Label(root, text="Enter the time:")
label.config(font=labelfont)
label.config(height=3, width=20)
label.pack()

global e
e = Entry(root)
e.pack(ipady=3)
e.focus_set()

root.mainloop()

#create Matplotlib live graph    
def makePlot():

    # Parameters
    x_len = t        # Number of points to display
    y_range = [0,1]  # Range of possible Y values to display

    # Create figure for plotting
    fig = plt.figure()
    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mng.resize(*mng.window.maxsize())
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = list(range(0, x_len))
    ys = [0] * x_len
    ax.set_ylim(y_range)

    # Create a blank line. We will update the line in animate
    line, = ax.plot(xs, ys)

    # Add labels
    plt.title('Pressure')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Pressure(psi)')

    # This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
    def animate(i, ys):

        #get value from sensor
        x1 = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
        x2 = ((x1*4.096)/32767.0)*.00176678

        # Add y to list
        ys.append(x2)

        # Limit y list to set number of items
        ys = ys[-x_len:]

        # Update line with new Y values
        line.set_ydata(ys)

        return line,

    # Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
        animate,
        fargs=(ys,),
        interval=300,
        blit=True)
    plt.show()


#info panel code    
root = Tk()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (1024, 75, 0, 0))

x1 = adc.read_adc(0, gain=1)
x2 = ((x1*4.096)/32767.0)*.00176678
x3 = '%.3f' % x2
var = x3

labelfont = ('times', 20, 'bold')

label1 = Label(root, text="[Timer]")
label1.pack(side=LEFT)
label2 = Label(root, text=var)
label2.pack(side=LEFT)

label1.config(font=labelfont)
label1.config(height=3, width=35)

label2.config(font=labelfont)
label2.config(height=3, width=35)

def countdown(count):
    var2 = "Time", "left:", count
    label1.config(text=var2) 

    if count > 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)
    if count == 0:
        var3 = "Test", "ended"
        label1.config(text=var3,bg="red")
        return


def update():
    x1 = adc.read_adc(0, gain=1)
    x2 = ((x1*4.096)/32767.0)*.00176678
    x3 = '%.3f' % x2
    var = "Pressure:", x3, "psi"
    label2.config(text=var)
    root.after(500, update)

#This is where I am unsure of what to do...

root.after(500, update)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tested all components of this code and they all work individually. I just cannot seem to put it all together. I'm guessing I will need to use some sorting of multithreading, but I was unsuccessful in finding any similar questions online.